# Instantiating objects inline or not

Tags: c#

I usually instantiate arrays inline, because I think it's cleaner. But I've seen a lot of people instantiating them when they're first needed. Is there any reason to do so, except for style?

This question is not only for arrays but in general. (Arrays, Objects, Primitives, ...)

```
private static List<IUndoable> undoables = new List<IUndoable>();

public static void AddUndoable()
{

}
```

vs

```
private static List<IUndoable> undoables;

public static void AddUndoable()
{
    if(undoables == null)
       undoables = new List<IUndoable>();
}
```

And would there be any difference in reasoning if the object is `non-static`?

Comment: You would use the second approach when you want **lazy instantiation.**  From [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization): *"If objects have properties that are rarely used, this can improve startup speed. Mean average program performance may be slightly worse in terms of memory (for the condition variables) and execution cycles (to check them), but the impact of object instantiation is spread in time ("amortized") rather than concentrated in the startup phase of a system, and thus median response times can be greatly improved."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach is safer from the following perspectives:

1. It is guaranteed to happen.
2. It happens as part of class loading so is thread safe.

You can imagine that the other approach is:

1. Error prone if someone fails to invoke the static method.
2. Thread unsafe with a very small window during which two threads might try to initialize the array, and at some point, someone sees the first array and other the second.

Non-static does not change the above arguments.

Comment: This answer is correct, but incomplete, since it does not explain the cases where the second approach makes more sense. Hence a reader might get the wrong impression the first one is always "better" than the second.

Comment: The second approach is also _slightly_ safer in that it can handle cases where the array was erroneously set to `null` somewhere inbetween the initialization and now. You'd need a `const` (or `readonly` if not static) to prevent this with the first approach.

Comment: @Flater: to be fair, when the array was  cases was erroneously set to null in between, it would probably a bug also in the second case, with the drawback that the second approach sweeps this silently under the rug, whilst the the first one does not. I would not call masking a bug "safer", quite the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Your example shows an eager allocation of memory vs a lazy allocation, not really that big of a deal in your example but it could be a consideration.  As a comparison to VB.NET, both examples give other methods the ability to do that allocation and to create new allocations as desired.  VB would allow you to isolate the usage so that it could not be directly accessed which you simply can’t do in C#.

Generally this is a question of scope, where do you want it used and by whom. C# is, as I said, lacking in this respect, so it doesn’t really make that much of a difference.  The only thing you can do to indicate the extra level of isolation is to use a private property, which will at least weakly convey that there might be an intention to keep it isolated and unused elsewhere.